# WPF Binding Datagrid to List of ObservableCollections of different types

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

This could probably be solved from different angles, but I'm kind of stuck right now.

I want to have a Datagrid, which can add Data of different types into lists in the backend.
I have a list of ObservableCollections, which all have different types of elements in it (I'm using MVVM and I have a couple of different model classes). In my frontend, I have a DataGrid, which is supposed to display the data of the lists depending on which value is selected in a Combobox. It also has to happen dynamicly and can't use fixed grids, as things are added and removed constantly.

I got the Binding to work, so it displays the lists if there are any entries by making the lists the type ObservableCollection.
However, if they are empty, the column headers will disappear and thus, the user cannot enter a new row of the correct type, which is necessary.

This is what I use right now to initiate the Collections:

```
                foreach (var lvm in ListOfValues)
                {
                    Type listType = lvm.GetListType();
                    string lvmName = listType.Name;

                    // Create ObservableCollection
                    ObservableCollection<object> observableCollection = new ObservableCollection<object>
                    {
                        // add a basic line to signal the list type - THIS IS A WORKAROUND
                        Activator.CreateInstance(listType),
                    };

                    TemplateEntries.Add(new TemplateEntry { ListName = lvmName, Values = observableCollection });
                }
```

Each TemplateEntry from the class contains the before named list of data. The TemplateEntries Property is just an ObservableCollection of TemplateEntries:

```
    public ObservableCollection<TemplateEntry> TemplateEntries { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<TemplateEntry>();

    public class TemplateEntry : ObservableObject
    {
        public string ListName { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<object> Values { get; set; }

        public int Count { get { return Values.Count; } }
    }
```

And in XAML I just have this line so far to display it:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5,5,5,5" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Name="Grid" CanUserAddRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding ValuesToDisplay}" />
```

So my question: How can I remove the Activator.CreateInstance Line workaround and signal the datagrid which type it should use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time, I managed to figure it out myself. The solution was to use the non-generic type IList instead of ObservableCollection for the Values of the TemplateEntry class, then cast the ObservableCollection into it (after creating it using Reflection). The DataGrid will accept this.

```
foreach (var lvm in ListModel.ListVMs)
            {
                Type listType = lvm.GetListType();
                string lvmName = listType.Name;

                Type collectionType = typeof(ObservableCollection<>).MakeGenericType(listType);

                // Create ObservableCollection
                IList observableCollection = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(collectionType);

                TemplateEntries.Add(new TemplateEntry { ListName = lvmName, Values = observableCollection });
            }
```

Comment: Nice work done. That i snot the best way to do but you can mark this answer as solution so your question will be shown as solved.